# SQL query with repeated values in list

Tags: mysql, sql

How to write a query correctly to get data without uniqueness?

I have list of ids, where ids are repeated.

Example: (1,1,1,2,3)

```
select * 
from table 
where id in (1,1,1,2,3);
```

returns only (1,2,3).

But I need to get with repeated entries.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Show sample input data and desired output. It's not clear why you want to duplicate rows at runtime, if they don't actually exist as duplicates, so some context would be good also.

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived table and `left join`:

```
select t.*
from (select 1 as id union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) i left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id
```

The syntax for the derived table might vary depending on the database, but most support the above syntax.

Comment: And if I have a large list of values, can you somehow point to this list?

Comment: This will return rows with nulls in case any of 1,1,1,2,3 do not exist in the table.

Comment: @user8814926 . . . The list, in fact, is perhaps better implemented using a table.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what WHERE statement is for, as it's only for filtering matching keys.

If you need to do that in this order, use sth like

```sql
select table.* 
from (
  select 1 as id
  union select 1
  union select 1
  union select 2
  union select 3
) myStaticKeys
join table using (id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this query still removes the repeated values. I am use mysql

Comment: @user8814926 this answer is correct but you will have to use `union all` instead of `union`.